# Root VC being deallocated by a second modal

Tags: ios, swift, view-hierarchy

Recently I have developed a custom modal animation using the UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate where the calling view controller should be visible after the transition, i.e. its modal is over context.

The problem arises when the presented view controller calls another modal (the facebook login modal in this case). When this second modal is dismissed the root view controller, that should be still visible, is gone.
Does anyone have a clue on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how do you dismiss the second modal

Comment: you can use a novigationcontroller. It will let your new VC present on top of the older one (stacked) Thus you wont have your views deallocated. If you dont prefer using UINavigationController please post some code and tag me in a comment to help you out!

Comment: @Shubhank I don't have any control over the second modal because it is the facebook login modal. I just pass the reference of the vc that should call this modal.

Comment: @BashirSidani Maybe the answer to Shubank suits for you too. Or I didn't understand what you mean hehehe Anyway, thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try add a **strong** reference of your rootVC in your modal. This might work because if the OS tries deallocate your root, the strong reference will maintain allocated.